# Has the "Use Alpa" option for textures been changed?

Tags: texturing, image, transparency

I'm using .dds textures and I just upgraded to 2.76. Many of the textures I'm handling have an alpha channel that must be disabled. In 2.73 there was a checkbox on the textures tab that said "use alpha". It doesn't seem to be there now. Is this a change or a bug? Also is there another way I can change the alpha option?

Comment: it should still be under texture panel, in the "image sampling" group... (I have it in 2.76, it seems enabled by default)

Comment: For some reason the checkbox sometimes isn't there. I found it can be changed with python.

Answer (score 1):

still on 2.76? Could something be happened to your installed copy UI somehow, using python? I re-downloaded a fresh 2.76b today from http://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.76/

and **there is** the option, there (here using a png image with transparency):

[image]

Comment: I've had several copies here. It seems if you scroll down from the top you have the option, if you scroll up from the bottom you don't. Haven't tried newer versions of blender.